# How to scale thickness or strokeWidth of line when screen size changes

Tags: android, canvas

I am playing around with an application that draws and traces the user's finger on the canvas.  See this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kstUK.png), the green rectangle was drawn by tracing the user's finger motion.  I took most of the code from the old FingerPaint application from the android SDK samples. The gist of it is to draw a Path on a canvas with:

```
    canvas.drawPath (path, paint)
```

My first challenge was to redraw the path correctly when the screen changes. For example, when the phone gets rotated from vertical to horizontal, the image gets resized and I have to redraw the path along the correct coordinates.  I was able to correctly do that with [transform](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#transform(android.graphics.Matrix)). I used the path.transform(matrix) to translate the coordinates of the path.

My next challenge now is to properly scale the thickness of the line. When I draw the path, the thickness of line is set with setStrokeWidth. For example, I set the thickness to 12:

```
    paint.setStrokeWidth(12);
```

I don't know how to properly scale the thickness of the line when the screen changes. Would anynone know how to do that ?

A suggestion would be to first save the canvas and the path as a bitmap and then redraw the bitmap on the new screen dimensions.  But I don't want to do that because I want to support a undo/redo operations where the user can undo/redo the paths that were traced on the canvas.

Comment: are you using a custom `ImageView` with overriden `onDraw` method? or draw your `Bitmap` by yourself in your custom `View`?

Comment: I draw the bitmap myself on my own custom view

Comment: by using  `Canvas#drawBitmap(Bitmap, Matrix, Paint)` maybe? or you use `Canvas#scale` / `Canvas#concat`?

Comment: I have my own custom view. In the `onDraw(canvas)` method of my custom view I do 2 things. First, `canvas.drawBitmap(...)` to draw the picture.  Second, `canvas.drawPath(path, paint)` to draw the path the user has traced with his finger. Upon screen rotation, `onDraw(canvas)` gets invoked for my view to be redrawn because the screen dimension has changed. At that point, I was able to successfully translate the coordinates of the path so that `canvas.drawPath(path, paint)` renders the path at the correct location. But I don't know yet how to properly scale the thickness of the path.

Comment: yes i know, my question is how do you scale your bitmap to fit the new dimension after screen rotation?

Comment: I see, to draw the bitmap on the canvas, I am using this variant of `drawBitmap(bitmap, src, dst, paint)`. I pass null for the _src_ rectangle. For the _dst_ rectangle, I compute the largest rectangle that will fit on the canvas and has the same aspect ratio as the bitmap. `drawBitmap` then does the job of scaling the bitmap to that _dst_ rectangle.

Comment: better use `Canvas#drawBitmap(Bitmap, Matrix, Paint)` and compute the `Matrix` in `onSizeChanged` by simply calling `Matrix#setRectToRect` - then use the same `Matrix` to find out the stroke width - either by `mapRect` or `mapPoints` or `mapRadius` (btw you could use that matrix for calling `Path#transform` too)

Comment: Thanks @pskink, I could use that to draw the bitmap. But my problem is to draw the path (not the bitmap) with the correct stroke width.

Comment: ... - then use the same `Matrix` to find out the stroke width - either by `mapRect` or `mapPoints` or `mapRadius`

Comment: see https://pastebin.com/raw/6QC6nrzV

Comment: Thanks @pskink I think I got what you mean. I will experiment with that.

Comment: of course replace `mapRadius(1)` with something more clever - most likely by scaling `1` with `DisplayMetrics` density

Answer (score 0):

you can use sth like this:

```
float screenWidthPixel  = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
float screenHeightPixel = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

float STROKE_WIDTH = screenWidthPixel * 0.0035f;
float Y_POSITION   = screenHeightPixel * 0.01f;

paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
```